# .Net Deploying application that use Excel

Tags: .net, vsto

I develop an application that use the Microsoft.Interop.Excel version 11 in .Net 3.5

How could I deploy it to a machine that doesn't have Microsoft Office 2003 installed  ?

Did I absolutely need a full office license ? I hope no ...

Comment: Yes, VSTO required Office fully installed. In this prise you get fully functional Office API wrappers. Or use 3rd-party products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install excel on the machine that is running it. For this you need an office license that covers Excel. Pretty much every type of office license covers Excel, try looking for the most basic edition (word, excel, powerpoint I think it contains);

Answer (score 0):

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449186/replacement-for-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll-where-excel-is-not-required-c) discussed some of the alternatives, but I don't know if they'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to use the Interop you need Excel to be installed. If you're interested I produced a list of 3rd party libraries recently that can read from Excel because we need server automation (which you can't do with the Interop).

We opted for FlexCel which I replaced our Interop calls with in no time at all, and it's been very easy to use since with excellent support, at a very low cost.
[Excel Readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273116/reading-excel-files-as-a-server-process)